# Variable calculations using rows that satisfy a condition

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I'm trying to work out a mean of a variable using rows that are equal to another value using:

```
pp$mmean[pp[,1] == '1'] <- mean(pp$mm)[1:nrow(pp[,1] == '1')]
```

That is I'm trying to work out the mean of mm - using rows where the first column == 1 (excluding every other row if it doesn't equal 1) where the pp$mmean result will only be indicated next to these rows.  The above code gives me:

```
Error in 1:nrow(pp[, 1] == "1") : argument of length 0
```

I want to do this multiple times for every unique value in pp[,1]... and will set up a for loop for this.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here...

Example of data, pp:

```
Plan X mm
1 95 0.323    
1 275 0.341818    
1 2 0.618   
1 75 0.32     
1 13 0.399    
1 20 0.40     
2 219 0.393    
2 50 0.060 
2 213 0.39    
2 204 0.4961     
2 19 0.393    
2 201 0.388
```

etc...

Comment: About Your error - when You are subsetting one column from a data.frame like this `pp[,1]` the result coerces to a vector, so it has no dimensions, so `nrow` returns `NULL` and `1:nrow(...)` throws an error. `length` would work correctly, or if You want to retain data.frame structure while subsetting one column You should use `drop` argument, like this `pp[, 1, drop = FALSE]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try `ave`. With the default arguments, `ave` calculates `mean` for each level of the grouping variable(s), but the resulting vector has the same length as the original data.

```
pp$mean_mm <- with(pp, ave(mm, Plan))

#    Plan   X       mm  mean_mm
# 1     1  95 0.323000 0.400303
# 2     1 275 0.341818 0.400303
# 3     1   2 0.618000 0.400303
# 4     1  75 0.320000 0.400303
# 5     1  13 0.399000 0.400303
# 6     1  20 0.400000 0.400303
# 7     2 219 0.393000 0.353350
# 8     2  50 0.060000 0.353350
# 9     2 213 0.390000 0.353350
# 10    2 204 0.496100 0.353350
# 11    2  19 0.393000 0.353350
# 12    2 201 0.388000 0.353350
```

**Edit** following comment; `ave` over multiple columns. One possibility is to loop over columns on which mean should be calculated using `sapply`.

```
# sample data
pp <- data.frame(Plan = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), mm = 1:9, mm1 = 2:10, mm2 = 3:11)

# name of variables for which mean should be calculated 
vars <- c("mm", "mm1", "mm2")

# 'loop' over variables using sapply
m <- sapply(vars, function(x){
  pp2 <- pp[ , c("Plan", x)]
  ave(pp2[ , x], pp2[ , "Plan"])
  })

# rename columns of result matrix
colnames(m) <- paste0("mean_", vars)

# add means to original data
cbind(pp, m)
```

Comment: Just to add: say that I had multiple mm columns, say mm, mm1 and mm2 (in columns V3 to V5) - can one use: pp$mean_mm <- with(pp, ave(pp[,3:5], Plan)) to get the mean of all these columns in each Plan?  It didn't seem to work for me (I get 40 warnings)

Answer (score 1):

Many built-in options:

`by(pp$mm, pp$X, mean, na.rm=T)`
`tapply(pp$mm, pp$X, mean, na.rm=T)`

using `plyr`:

```
library(plyr)
ddply( pp, .(X), mean)
```

using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
pp = data.table(pp)
pp[,mean(mm,na.rm=T),by="X"]
```

if you want to set it directly in your data.table:

```
pp[,AVERAGEbyX:=mean(mm,na.rm=T),by="X"]
```

not to mention `mapply` and `aggregate`

Here is an overview of the R built-in options: [Using tapply for the subset group of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162260/using-tapply-for-the-subset-group-of-data/21162379#21162379)

Comment: They are helpful suggestions.  However I get the error when running these `Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, mmean", value = c(0.400303,  : replacement has 6 rows, data has 87 `

Comment: These don't put them straight in your data.frame, they just give the average by X. To put it into your frame you would use `data.table`'s `:=` notation (`pp[,AVERAGEbyX:=mean(mm,na.rm=T),by="X"]`) or Henrik's `with` call.