# Find average of data for each month in a dataset

Tags: r, date, dataframe

The dataset consists of a company identifier (a string), three columns of data values and a date (yyyymmdd). There are around 25,500 unique company identifiers and each has daily values from Jan. 1 1973 to the present for a total of around 700,000 rows. What I would like to do is calculate some statistics (i.e. range, mean, median, SD, etc) for each date in the dataset. The data was originally a csv and was imported into R as a dataframe. My first attempt is below but I was wondering if there is a more efficient method than looping through 25,000 rows

```
stat <- data.frame(Date=as.Date(character()), Mean=numeric(), SD=numeric(), Quant_75=numeric(), Quant_25=numeric(), Range=numeric(), stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 
uniq <- unique(unlist(data$Date))
for (i in 1:length(uniq)){
data_sub <- subset(data, date == uniq[i])
stat[i,] = rbind(date, mean(data_sub), sd(data_sub), quantile(data_sub, 0.75), quantile(data_sub,0.25), range(data_sub) )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plethora of options for doing this in R: a couple of them [native to R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162260/using-tapply-for-the-subset-group-of-data/21162379#21162379), others like [plyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega/7141669#7141669) and [sqldf](http://www.r-bloggers.com/applying-functions-on-groups-sqldf-plyr-doby-or-aggregate/) have their own package. I would recommed the `data.table` package because of its speed on large data sets. On your data something like:

```
require(data.table)
data = data.table(data)
data[,list(AVG_BY_DAY:=mean(COLNAME1,na.rm=T),SD_BY_DAY:=sd(COLNAME2,na.rm=T,Q_75_BY_DAY=quantile(COLNAME3,0.75)) ),by="Date"]
data[,list(AVG_BY_COMPANY:=mean(COLNAME1,na.rm=T),SD_BY_COMPANY:=sd(COLNAME2,na.rm=T,Q_75_BY_COMPANY=quantile(COLNAME3,0.75)) ),by="Company"]
```

Check out [this link](http://blog.yhathq.com/posts/10-R-packages-I-wish-I-knew-about-earlier.html), it could be useful to anybody handling data in R.

Comment: Actually I am getting the following error. Error in `:=`(AVG_BY_DAY, mean(technical$PRC, na.rm = T)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").

Comment: you don't need to specify the data.table name: so "`:=`(AVG,mean(PRC,na.rm=T))" should suffice. Also make sure PRC is numeric and not a factor + don't forget the backticks around `:=` (invisible in the comments because it is used for quoting code on stackoverflow) if you use the notation `:=`(AVG=mean(PRC,na.rm=T),SD=sd(PRC,na.rm=T)) instead of `list(AVG:=mean(...),SD:=sd(...)`